# No colored tags for meta newsletter

Tags: bug, meta, newsletter

The meta tags ([status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed),[bug](/questions/tagged/bug), etc.) don't show in the right colors in the newsletter. Instead, they look like boring old tags [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)[bug](/questions/tagged/bug).
[image: poorly colored newsletter]